# JAVA 8 : need to perform List iteration in stream and convert list of another object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of object List(Item) from service.
I want to convert the List(Item) list  to DB table ItemEntity object using Java 8 stream. In that List(Item) Item-> have VarietyList, if the VarietyList(itemVariety) have data then need to create that many ItemEntity object. if the VarietyList(itemVariety) is empty then need to create one ItemEntity object.

Below Java for each code works perfectly, i need this code in JAVA 8 Stream function.

```
    List<Item> itemList = from some services;

    List<ItemEntity> itemEnt= new ArrayList();

    for (Item item : itemsList) {
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(item.getVarietyList())) {
                for (ItemVariety itemVariety : item.getVarietyList()) {
                    itemEnt.add(loadItemData(item , itemVariety));
                }
            } else {
                itemEnt.add(loadItemData(item, null));
            }
    }               



    private ItemEntity loadItemData(Item itemType, ItemVariety itemVariety) {
            ItemEntity itemEntity = new ItemEntity();
            itemEntity.setName(itemType.getName());
            if (itemVariety != null) {
                itemEntity.setVarietyName(itemVariety .getName());
            }

            return cropEntity;
        }
```

Please suggest me the best way in JAVA8

Comment: did you try to something like  `itemList.stream().forEach( il ->{ do your action });`?

Comment: as @AngeloImmediata suggested or itemList.stream().map(item -> some action);

Comment: itemList.stream().map(item -> loadItemData(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());

 private ItemEntity loadItemData(Item itemType) {
            ItemEntity itemEntity = new ItemEntity(); ... like this i tried

Comment: but that condition variety list we can't return in map( method ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, a for loop over a list of instances of class `A` that creates an instance of a class `B` for each item in the original list can be turned into

```
List<A> as = .... ;
List<B> = as.stream().map(a -> createB(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where

```
private B createB(A a) {
//returns new B() based on given a
}
```

When for each item in the original list you can create more than one instance of B, you for loop can be turned into

```
List<A> as = .... ;
List<B> = as
    .stream()
    .flatMap(a -> CreateBs(a))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where

```
private Stream<B> createBs(A a) {
    // returns Stream<B> based on a
}
```

You are in the second scenario, so you `createBs(A)` is

```
private Stream<ItemEntity> createItemEntity(Item item) {
    return item.getVarietyList().isEmpty() ?
        Stream.of(loadItemData(item, null)) :
        item.getVarietyList().stream(x -> mapItemVarietyToItemEntity(item, x));
}

private ItemEntity mapItemVarietyToItemEntity(Item item, ItemVariety variety) {
    loadItemData(item, variety);
}
```

I can't run the code above at the moment, but I hope it can help you toward the solution you're searching for.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wants to use the stream api you could do it something like below, but IMO it's much more readable in plain old java.

```
List<ItemEntity> itemEnt = itemsList.stream()
    .flatMap(item -> {
        return CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(item.getVarietyList()) 
            ? item.getVarietyList.stream().map(variety -> loadItemData(item, variety))
            : Stream.of(loadItemData(item, null))
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());


private ItemEntity loadItemData(Item itemType, ItemVariety itemVariety) {
    ItemEntity itemEntity = new ItemEntity();
    itemEntity.setName(itemType.getName());
    if (itemVariety != null) {
        itemEntity.setVarietyName(itemVariety .getName());
    }
    return cropEntity;
}
```